# How can I count the presence of different values in a long list of specific columns with Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count

I have 25 columns and 5 rows here. I need to count the values in specific columns only once per row. Was the value '1' present in this row of data between these columns? If yes, then count it. And so on with the other values.

There are other columns that also contain these values, but they should not be counted in these columns. Only Columns x y, x = [1,2] and y = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]. Not x = ['a','b','c','d','e'].

Edit: Explained in another way: "between these columns, in how many rows does 1 appear, in how many rows does 2 appear..."

```
data = {'Column 1 1':     [ 1, 3, 3, 2, 4], 
        'Column 1 2':     [ 3,'', 4, 3, 5], 
        'Column 1 3':     [ 4,'', 3, 4, 7],
        'Column 1 4':     ['','', 4, 1, 7],
        'Column 1 5':     ['','', 6, 5, 8],
        'Column 1 6':     ['','', 6,'', 3],
        'Column 1 7':     ['','', 8,'', 2],
        'Column 1 8':     ['','', 3,'',''],
        'Column 1 9':     ['','', 1,'',''],
        'Column 1 10':    ['','', 7,'',''],
        'Column 2 1':     [ 2, 5, 5, 1, 4], 
        'Column 2 2':     ['','', 4, 3,''], 
        'Column 2 3':     ['','','', 2, 7],
        'Column 2 4':     ['','', 4, 1,''],
        'Column 2 5':     ['','', 7, 5, 8],
        'Column 2 6':     ['','', 6,'', 3],
        'Column 2 7':     ['','','','', 2],
        'Column 2 8':     ['','','','',''],
        'Column 2 9':     ['','','','',''],
        'Column 2 10':    ['','', 8,'',''],
        'Column a':       [ 1, 2, 4, 5, 5],
        'Column b':       [ 8, 7, 6, 3, 2],
        'Column c':       [ 7, 3, 4, 3, 2],
        'Column d':       [ 2, 2, 3, 7, 7],
        'Column e':       [ 4, 3, 7, 4, 1]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
```

What I want is a dataframe with a table that says

- 1: 3
- 2: 3
- 3: 5 (notice it is not counted twice for a row if it appears more than once)
- 4: 4
- 5: 4
- 6: 1
- 7: 2
- 8: 2

.value_counts() only lets me do one column at a time and if I sum up data of value_counts for all these 20 columns, it will give me a too high number, because some appear in more columns for each row.

Comment: Can you please explain the query again?

Comment: I added some explanation. Does that make sense?

Comment: I forgot to add your name @hashdefine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The strategy here is melt your data down into row, value pairs, and then count the distinct sets of these. First, get the columns you want to keep as a list:

```
cols = [f"Column {x} {y}" for y in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] for x in [1, 2]]
```

Then, transpose your data so that you have a column for every row and a row for every column:

```
df[cols].transpose()                                                                                                                                                                               

             0  1  2  3  4
Column 1 1   1  3  3  2  4
Column 2 1   2  5  5  1  4
Column 1 2   3     4  3  5
Column 2 2         4  3   
Column 1 3   4     3  4  7
...
```

Then melt this down into variable, value pairs ('variable' is the row) and dedupe:

```
df[cols].transpose().melt().drop_duplicates()

    variable value
0          0     1
1          0     2
2          0     3
3          0      
4          0     4
20         1     3
21         1     5
22         1      
...
```

Finally, group by your values and get a count of the distinct number of rows each appears in:

```
df[cols].transpose().melt().drop_duplicates().groupby('value').count()        

       variable
value          
1             3
2             3
3             5
4             4
5             4
6             1
7             2
8             2
              5
```

Filter out the blanks before the groupby if you want.

Answer (score -1):

NOTE: I replaced `''` with `0` in your dataframe.

Then I created a series which contained all the unique values in each row.

```
def get_unique(x):
    return np.unique(x.values)
df2 = df.apply(get_unique,axis=1)
df2
0       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8]
1             [0, 2, 3, 5, 7]
2    [0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
3       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7]
4    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8]
dtype: object
```

Then I counted the occurance of values in each array of unique values.

```
pd.Series({i: df2.map(lambda x: i in x).sum() for i in range(10)})
0    5
1    4
2    4
3    5
4    4
5    4
6    1
7    5
8    3
9    0
```